# Growing arrays in Haskell

Tags: arrays, haskell

I have the following (imperative) algorithm that I want to implement in Haskell:

Given a sequence of pairs [(e0,s0), (e1,s1), (e2,s2),...,(en,sn)], where both "e" and "s" parts are natural numbers not necessarily different, at each time step one element of this sequence is randomly selected, let's say (ei,si), and based in the values of (ei,si), a new element is built and added to the sequence.

How can I implement this efficiently in Haskell? The need for random access would make it bad for lists, while the need for appending one element at a time would make it bad for arrays, as far as I know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Based on the values of (ei, si), a new element is built and added to the sequence"...what? Why are additional elements appended to the sequence? This makes me think there may be a better, purer way of reconstructing this algorithm. Are elements consumed when they are selected? If so, then why not just replace the old element with the new? (Arrays would work well for this)

Comment: @Dan: This is a piece of a "preferential attachment" algorithm, where an event is a pair, and each part of the pair is either a new thing (that is, the next number) or an old one. If it is the old one, then the prob. of choosing any particular value is proportional to its previous occurrences. So, given the sequence [(1,1),(1,2),(2,3)] then the next pair would have, for the first element, probs 1->2/3, 2->1/3 and for the second one 1->1/3, 2->1/3 and 3->1/3. The easiest way to sample here is just to take two random elements of the secuence and copy their components... or so I think.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest using either `Data.Set` or `Data.Sequence`, depending on what you're needing it for.  The latter in particular provides you with logarithmic index lookup (as opposed to linear for lists) and O(1) appending on either end.

Comment: Four years forward in time, I've realized that logarithmic complexity is a small price to pay sometimes... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

"while the need for appending one element at a time would make it bad for arrays" Algorithmically, it seems like you want a dynamic array (aka vector, array list, etc.), which has amortized O(1) time to append an element. I don't know of a Haskell implementation of it off-hand, and it is not a very "functional" data structure, but it is definitely possible to implement it in Haskell in some kind of state monad.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Actually it's not possible to implement O(1) random access arrays without them being provided to you as a primitive. A state monad can help you abstract over the arrays implementation, but won't help you write one.

Comment: @Rotsor: but ghc has arrays, mutable ones, so I should probably be able to use ST monad, STRef, and these arrays to implement some statefull array list... I can not think of something better. At the end, I should be able to get amortized O(1)...

Comment: Ok. This is the closest answer. I appreciate all the suggestions for using sets, but I think that there is no need to compromise performance if it can be done with a grow-able array. Thanks to all that submitted answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you know approx how much total elements you will need then you can create an array of such size which is "sparse" at first and then as need you can put elements in it. 
Something like below can be used to represent this new array:

```
data MyArray = MyArray (Array Int Int) Int
```

(where the last Int represent how many elements are used in the array)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need stop-and-start resizing, you could think about using the [simple-rope](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/simple-rope/0.1/doc/html/Data-Rope.html) package along with a `StringLike` instance for something like `Vector`. In particular, this might accommodate scenarios where you start out with a large array and are interested in relatively small additions.

That said, adding individual elements into the chunks of the rope may still induce a lot of copying. You will need to try out your specific case, but you should be prepared to use a mutable vector as you may not need pure intermediate results.

If you can build your array in one shot and just need the indexing behavior you describe, something like the following may suffice,

```
import Data.Array.IArray

test :: Array Int (Int,Int)
test = accumArray (flip const) (0,0) (0,20) [(i, f i) | i <- [0..19]]
  where f 0 = (1,0)
        f i = let (e,s) = test ! (i `div` 2) in (e*2,s+1)
```

Comment: Wow, someone has actually taken a look at my simple-rope package! The 2 hours at the airport have not been spent in vain :)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a note from ivanm, I think Sets are the way to go for this.

```
import Data.Set as Set
import System.Random (RandomGen, getStdGen)

startSet :: Set (Int, Int)
startSet = Set.fromList [(1,2), (3,4)] -- etc. Whatever the initial set is

-- grow the set by randomly producing "n" elements.
growSet :: (RandomGen g) => g -> Set (Int, Int) -> Int -> (Set (Int, Int), g)
growSet g s n | n <= 0    = (s, g)
              | otherwise = growSet g'' s' (n-1)
    where s' = Set.insert (x,y) s
          ((x,_), g')  = randElem s g
          ((_,y), g'') = randElem s g'

randElem :: (RandomGen g) => Set a -> g -> (a, g)
randElem = undefined

main = do
    g <- getStdGen
    let (grownSet,_) = growSet g startSet 2
    print $ grownSet -- or whatever you want to do with it
```

This assumes that `randElem` is an efficient, definable method for selecting a random element from a Set. (I asked [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349080/select-random-element-from-a-set-faster-than-linear-time-haskell/7354582#7354582) regarding efficient implementations of such a method). One thing I realized upon writing up this implementation is that it may not suit your needs, since `Set`s cannot contain duplicate elements, and my algorithm has no way to give extra weight to pairings that appear multiple times in the list.

Comment: There is a multiset package on Hackage if multiple elements are required (it uses `Map a Int` under the hood) and you want to use a set-like data structure.