# Select random element from a set, faster than linear time (Haskell)

Tags: performance, haskell, random, set

I'd like to create this function, which selects a random element from a [Set](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Set.html#t:Set):

```
randElem :: (RandomGen g) => Set a -> g -> (a, g)
```

Simple listy implementations can be written. For example (code updated, verified working):

```
import Data.Set as Set
import System.Random (getStdGen, randomR, RandomGen)

randElem :: (RandomGen g) => Set a -> g -> (a, g)
randElem s g = (Set.toList s !! n, g')
    where (n, g') = randomR (0, Set.size s - 1) g

-- simple test drive
main = do g <- getStdGen
          print . fst $ randElem s g
    where s = Set.fromList [1,3,5,7,9]
```

But using `!!` incurs a linear lookup cost for large (randomly selected) `n`. Is there a faster way to select a random element in a Set? Ideally, repeated random selections should produce a uniform distribution over all options, meaning it does not prefer some elements over others.

---

**Edit**: some great ideas are popping up in the answers, so I just wanted to throw a couple more clarifications on what exactly I'm looking for. I asked this question with Sets as the solution to [this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342862/growing-arrays-in-haskell) in mind. I'll prefer answers that both

1. avoid using any outside-the-function bookkeeping beyond the Set's internals, and
2. maintain good performance (better than *O(n)* on average) even though the function is only used once per unique set.

I also have this love of working code, so expect (at minimum) a +1 from me if your answer includes a working solution.

Comment: Related food for thought: [source for Python's random.sample()](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an idea: You could do interval bisection.

1. `size s` is constant time. Use `randomR` to get how far into the set you are selecting.
2. Do `split` with various values between the original `findMin` and `findMax` until you get the element at the position you want. If you really fear that the set is made up say of reals and is extremely tightly clustered, you can recompute `findMin` and `findMax` each time to guarantee knocking off some elements each time.

The performance would be O(n log n), basically no worse than your current solution, but with only rather weak conditions to the effect that the set not be entirely clustered round some accumulation point, the average performance should be ~((logn)^2), which is fairly constant. If it's a set of integers, you get O(log n * log m), where m is the initial range of the set; it's only reals that could cause really nasty performance in an interval bisection (or other data types whose order-type has accumulation points).

PS. This produces a perfectly even distribution, as long as watching for off-by-ones to make sure it's possible to get the elements at the top and bottom.

### Edit: added 'code'

Some inelegant, unchecked (pseudo?) code. No compiler on my current machine to smoke test, possibility of off-by-ones, and could probably be done with fewer `if`s. One thing: check out how `mid` is generated; it'll need some tweaking depending on whether you are looking for something that works with sets of ints or reals (interval bisection is inherently topological, and oughtn't to work quite the same for sets with different topologies).

```
import Data.Set as Set
import System.Random (getStdGen, randomR, RandomGen)

getNth (s, n) = if n = 0 then (Set.findMin s) else if n + 1 = Set.size s then Set.findMax s
    else if n < Set.size bott then getNth (bott, n) else if pres and Set.size bott = n then n
    else if pres then getNth (top, n - Set.size bott - 1) else getNth (top, n - Set.size)
    where mid = ((Set.findMax s) - (Set.findMin s)) /2 + (Set.findMin s)
          (bott, pres, top) = (splitMember mid s)

randElem s g = (getNth(s, n), g')
    where (n, g') = randomR (0, Set.size s - 1) g
```

Comment: Reason for downvote please? Thanks. So far, I think this is the only solution that satisfies the questioner's requirements of providing o(n) (ie <O(n) ) for a single call per Set.

Comment: I had my eye on this answer, it did look like it was closest to what I wanted. After looking at the code, despite the clutter, it does look like a decent implementation. You could clean up the ugly if/then sequence by turning it into guards. Also, you need to use `==` for equality comparison. But the idea behind the code looks good; I think this idea best fits my requirements.

Comment: This randElem has a different type (requiring numeric elements), so it doesn't solve the general problem. Also, if it matters, the worst case complexity is O(n*log(n)).

Comment: Yes, I remarked on those points. Informally, it's 'clear' from the interface of the Set type that the only approach that will work is seaching by value in some form; and, that is inherently dependant on the order-type of the elements of the set. This looks to be, sadly, roughly the optimal aproach.

Answer (score 7):

Data.Map has an indexing function (elemAt), so use this:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Map(member, size, empty)
import System.Random

type Set a = M.Map a ()

insert :: (Ord a) => a -> Set a -> Set a
insert a = M.insert a ()

fromList :: Ord a => [a] -> Set a
fromList = M.fromList . flip zip (repeat ())

elemAt i = fst . M.elemAt i

randElem :: (RandomGen g) => Set a -> g -> (a, g)
randElem s g = (elemAt n s, g')
    where (n, g') = randomR (0, size s - 1) g
```

And you have something quite compatible with Data.Set (with respect to interface and performance) that also has a log(n) indexing function and the randElem function you requested.

Note that randElem is log(n) (and it's probably the fastest implementation you can get with this complexity), and all the other functions have the same complexity as in Data.Set. Let me know if you need any other specific functions from the Set API and I will add them.

Comment: Given access to the internals of `Data.Set`, one could easily implement an _O(log n)_ `elemAt` for sets. It feels like an oversight that it's currently only defined for maps.

Comment: There is a ticket about this (http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5162) and some email discussion (http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2011-April/016286.html). I believe the reason it is not implemented is that it relies too heavily on the current implementation.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, the proper solution would be to use an indexed set -- i.e. an `IntMap`. You just need to store the total number of elements added along with the map. Every time you add an element, you add it with a key one higher than previously. Deleting an element is fine -- just don't alter the total elements counter. If, on looking up a keyed element, that element no longer exists, then generate a new random number and try again. This works until the total number of deletions dominates the number of active elements in the set. If that's a problem, you can keep a separate set of deleted keys to draw from when inserting new elements.

Comment: BTW, this has worse case complexety *O(∞)*, as it may be possible that the random generator only picks slots that are empty. One has to make sure, that there are always enough elements left. For instance, one could lower the number of elements if the highest element is removed.

Comment: But an avg case complexity O(log(n)) :-)

Comment: How do you come to this number?

Comment: @FUZxxl: careful thought :-) More seriously -- if there are no deletions, this is trivially the case. For m deletions it takes avg time `n/n-m` to generate a random number contained in the set with each "miss" costing the same lookup as the final "hit". So we really have `O(n/n-m * log (n))` which indeed goes to infinity as `n/n-m` gets large, but for any bounded ratio of holes to total size stays at O(log n)

Comment: Assuming that it's only possible to remove an integral number of elements, the only ways it can go to infinity are if `n` == `m`--i.e., deleting everything--or `n` == infinity in which case `log(n)` isn't really much better. So by handling the "all elements removed" case separately, the worst case scenario is a single element, which gives you `O(n)` tries to find it and `O(log n)` for each try, thus `O(n * log(n))` where `n` is the total added, not the actual count remaining.

Comment: To me the whole point of a `Set` is that it allows you to tell if an element is a member quickly (log time). This way does not let you do that.

Comment: @newacct: Yep. It doesn't use a set. But you can use a set alongside this with no impact on the order of magnitude of space cost.

Comment: @sclv Actually it does have an impact on the space complexity, since the map can contain duplicates.

Comment: @Jonas -- well, except you can use the set to efficiently enforce set rather than bag semantics for the map to begin with...

Answer (score 3):

If you had access to [the internals of Data.Set](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/src/Data.Set.html#Set), which is just a binary tree, you could recurse over the tree, at each node selecting one of the branches with probability according to their respective sizes. This is quite straight forward and gives you very good performance in terms of memory management and allocations, as you have no extra book-keeping to do. OTOH, you have to invoke the RNG O(log n) times.

A variant is using Jonas’ suggestion to first take the size and select the index of the random element based on that, and then use a (yet to be added elemAt) function to Data.Set.

Answer (score 3):

As of [containers-0.5.2.0](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.2.0) the `Data.Set` module has an `elemAt` function, which retrieves values by their zero-based index in the sorted sequence of elements. So it is now trivial to write this function

```
import           Control.Monad.Random
import           Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

randElem :: (MonadRandom m, Ord a) -> Set a -> m (a, Set a)
randElem xs = do
  n <- getRandomR (0, Set.size xs - 1)
  return (Set.elemAt n xs, Set.deleteAt n xs)
```

Since both `Set.elemAt` and `Set.deleteAt` are O(*log n*) where *n* is the number of elements in the set, the entire operation is O(*log n*)

Comment: Currently this is the best answer to the question. It's simple, _O(log n)_ and no access to `Set` internals is needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to modify your set or need to modify it infrequently you can use arrays as lookup table with O(1) access time.

```
import qualified Data.Vector 
import qualified Data.Set

newtype RandSet a = RandSet (V.Vector a)

randElem :: RandSet a -> RandomGen -> (a, RandomGen)
randElem (RandSet v) g
  | V.empty v = error "Cannot select from empty set" 
  | otherwise = 
    let (i,g') = randomR (0, V.length v - 1) g
    in (v ! i, g')

-- Of course you have to rebuild array on insertion/deletion which is O(n)
insert :: a -> RandSet a -> RandSet a
insert x = V.fromList . Set.toList . Set.insert x . Set.fromList . V.toList`
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be finessed a bit if you don't mind completely consuming your `RandomGen`. With splittable generators, this is an A-OK thing to do. The basic idea is to make a lookup table for the set:

```
randomElems :: Set a -> RandomGen -> [a]
randomElems set = map (table !) . randomRs bounds where
    bounds = (1, size set)
    table  = listArray bounds (toList set)
```

This will have very good performance: it will cost you O(n+m) time, where n is the size of the set and m is the number of elements of the resulting list you evaluate. (Plus the time it takes to randomly choose m numbers in bounds, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve this might be to use Data.Sequence instead of Data.Set. This would allow you to add elements to the end in O(1) time and index elements in O(log n) time. If you also need to be able to do membership tests or deletions, you would have to use the more general fingertree package and use something like `FingerTree (Sum 1, Max a) a`. To insert an element, use the `Max a` annotation to find the right place to insert; this basically takes O(log n) time (for some usage patterns it might be a bit less). To do a membership test, do basically the same thing, so it's O(log n) time (again, for some usage patterns this might be a bit less). To pick a random element, use the `Sum 1` annotation to do your indexing, taking O(log n) time (this will be the average case for uniformly random indices).

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe a lot of the answers are old here because now the set module has its own `elemAt` function to do this sort of thing very easily. Here's my implementation:

```
import Data.Set(Set)
import qualified Data.Set as S
import System.Random

randomMember :: RandomGen g => Set a -> g -> (Maybe a, g)
randomMember s g | null s = (Nothing, g)
                 | otherwise = let (a, g') = randomR (0, length s) g
                               in (Just (S.elemAt a s), g')
```

Prelude functions `null` and `length` work on sets as `Set` is an instance of `Foldable`.

```
hskl> newStdGen >>= return . fst . randomMember (S.fromList [1..10])
Just 7
hskl> newStdGen >>= return . fst . randomMember (S.fromList [1..10])
Just 4
hskl> newStdGen >>= return . fst . randomMember (S.fromList [1..10])
Just 4
hskl> newStdGen >>= return . fst . randomMember (S.fromList [1..10])
Just 9
hskl> newStdGen >>= return . fst . randomMember (S.fromList [1..10])
Just 8
hskl> newStdGen >>= return . fst . randomMember S.empty
Nothing
hskl> newStdGen >>= return . fst . randomMember S.empty
Nothing
```